# Error when i open app center

Tags: appcenter, release-hera

I am newbee or one might say a windows user i imagine that i a common joke in linux world,

anyway i move to elementary OS after deep search and i appreciate the simplicity and UX of it everything works fine but some time when i do something i get error when i start appcenter i manage to fix few with google help, but this once i keeps on coming back

```
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu bionic InRelease is not (yet) available (Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out)
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease is not (yet) available (Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:)
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease is not (yet) available (Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:)
```

i am using latest elementary OS release 5.1 Hera

any support to fic this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

so now when re open appcenter i get same error/aler box saying

E: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease is not (yet) available (Could not connect to dl.google.com:80 (172.217.19.46), connection timed out)
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu bionic InRelease is not (yet) available (Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83), connection timed out)
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease is not (yet) available (Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:)
E: http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease is not (yet) available (Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:)

guess its more issue, i hear to get off windows and start in the new home of linux which i love and i am here to learn about, thanks again

Note: 2 question same day u guyz will hate me for sure